# How to divide a large rectangle into N smaller rectangles

Tags: algorithms, rectangles

I would like to divide a NxMpx  rectangle(matrix) into X piece different size smaller rectangles. X is a variable so it dosn't have a fix value.The smaller rectangles must fill the 80-90% area  of large one. Small rectangles must to be different area.

[image]

Is there any algorithm or formula to solve this kind of problems.

(Ideas, links are welcome. I'v already searched a lot of websites with google, but unfortunately nothing usefull, maybe i am using wrong keywords or i don't know.)

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are so many ways that you have not specified what you want well enough. You can just split the rectangle into $N$ horizontal or vertical stripes.  You can cut those stripes as you do.  You can even make four rectangles that leave a little bit of space in the middle.